# How to solve the AttributeError:'list' object has no attribute 'astype'?

Tags: python, numpy, attributes

I am just wondering how to solve the attribute error in `python3.6.`
The error is

> 'list' object has no attribute 'astype'.

My related code is as blow.

```
def _init_mean_std(self, data):
    data = data.astype('float32')
    self.mean, self.std = np.mean(data), np.std(data)
    self.save_meanstd()
    return data
```

Is there anyone who can advice to me?

Thank you!

Comment: By converting `data` into something which possesses an attribute `astype`. Say, a numpy array. Doing `import numpy as np;data = np.array(data).astype('float32')`

Comment: I do not know if you do it voluntarily, but note that by default `np.array(data)` actually yields `float64`s. Check that by doing `print(data.dtype)`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The root issue is confusion of Python lists and NumPy arrays, which are different data types. NumPy methods that are invoked as `np.foo(array)` usually won't complain if you give them a Python list, they will convert it to an NumPy array silently. But if you try to invoke a method contained in the object, like `array.foo()` then of course it has to have the appropriate type already.

I would suggest using

```
data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
```

so that the type of an array is known to NumPy at once. This avoids unnecessary work where you first create an array and then cast it to another type.

NumPy recommends using [dtype objects](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html) instead of strings like "float32".