# How to change dtype of array of objects to string

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dtype

My question is similar to this question [How to solve the AttributeError:'list' object has no attribute 'astype'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46759801/how-to-solve-the-attributeerrorlist-object-has-no-attribute-astype/65499715?noredirect=1#comment115801323_65499715)
however, I'm trying to create a series of strings, in order to plot in graph.

```
 feature_names = df.iloc[:,maxIndex].columns
 newMaxName.append(feature_names)
 newMaxName = np.array(newMaxName, dtype =np.str)
 newMaxName
```

so it gives me output as

> array(['shar', 'dec', 'intel', 'like', 'amb', 'met', 'pid', 'prob_o',
> 'pf_o_sin', 'pf_o_att', 'pf_o_sha', 'pf_o_fun', 'age_o',
> 'pf_o_amb', 'pf_o_int', 'attr_o', 'attr', 'attr2_1', 'sinc',
> 'shar1_1', 'shar_o', 'amb_o', 'intel1_1', 'attr1_1', 'fun_o'],
> dtype='<U8')

I want them to be string how can I convert them?

Comment: Do you want to extract list of strings? `.tolist()` would do that. These are already strings in UTF-8

Comment: `dtype='<U8'` **is the string datatype**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16037824/14291629 might be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

You already did convert it to a string datatype, the default unicode string datatype:

```
>>> arr
array(['shar', 'dec', 'intel', 'like', 'amb', 'met', 'pid', 'prob_o',
       'pf_o_sin', 'pf_o_att', 'pf_o_sha', 'pf_o_fun', 'age_o',
       'pf_o_amb', 'pf_o_int', 'attr_o', 'attr', 'attr2_1', 'sinc',
       'shar1_1', 'shar_o', 'amb_o', 'intel1_1', 'attr1_1', 'fun_o'],
      dtype='<U8')
```

If you want byte-strins, be specific:

```
>>> arr.astype(np.dtype('S'))
array([b'shar', b'dec', b'intel', b'like', b'amb', b'met', b'pid',
       b'prob_o', b'pf_o_sin', b'pf_o_att', b'pf_o_sha', b'pf_o_fun',
       b'age_o', b'pf_o_amb', b'pf_o_int', b'attr_o', b'attr', b'attr2_1',
       b'sinc', b'shar1_1', b'shar_o', b'amb_o', b'intel1_1', b'attr1_1',
       b'fun_o'], dtype='|S8')
```

Note, byte-strings may be preferable, for memory purposes:

```
>>> arr.nbytes
800
>>> arr.astype(np.dtype('S')).nbytes
200
```

#### However

If your purpose is to plot, just working with `object` is almost certainly ok. Note, prior to version 1.00 `pandas` does not use any string-specific types, `object` *was* the string type.

If you are working with pandas you may want:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'1.1.1'
>>> s = pd.Series(['abc','def', 'ghi'])
>>> s
0    abc
1    def
2    ghi
dtype: object
>>> s.astype(pd.StringDtype())
0    abc
1    def
2    ghi
dtype: string
```

Comment: Yes ı want to plot in graph as yticks, like this ` plt.yticks(y_p,newMaxName) `, in the way arr.astype(np.dtype("S)) it works but the it work in horizontal , but it should be vertical since ı put them in graph, and the last part you said for pd.Series, this strings is the columns of the pandas

Comment: @Razbolt it works the same for a column in a dataframe. Your other problem seems totally unrelated to this. Again, almost certainly, you didn't have to do any conversion to begin with.