# Attribute error:'list' object has no attribute type 'astype'

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am trying to create neural network from scratch using python. But I am getting this kind of error. can anyone help me?

Code:

```
import numpy as py
import nnfs as nf ## import nnfs this is 
from nnfs.datasets import spiral_data

nf.init() # reset to the same number as before to check whethere it works.
X = [[1, 2, 3, 2.5],
     [2.0, 5.0, 1.0, 2.0],
     [1.5, 2.7, 3.3,0.8]]
##############
    ##weights =[[0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.5],[0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.5],[0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.5]]
    ##biases = [2,3,0.5]
    ##weights2 =[[0.1,-0.14,0.5],[-.5, 0.12, -.33],[-0.44, 0.73,-.13]]
    ##biases2 = [-1,2,-.5]
    ##layer1_output = py.dot(weights,py.transpose(input)) + biases # Dot product give shape of the each neuron. 
    ##layer2_output = py.dot(layer1_output,py.array(weights2).T) + biases2
    ##print(layer2_output)
#########################

##GENERATE DATASET###
x,y = spiral_data(100,3)

class Layer_Dense:
    def __init__(self, n_inputs,n_neurons): ##
      self.weights = 0.10 * py.random.randn(n_inputs,n_neurons) # size of input, shape of weight (shape of neuron = neuron X transposed input. )
      self.biases = py.zeros((1,n_neurons))
    def forward(self,inputs):
        self.output = py.dot(inputs, self.weights) + self.biases


class Activation_ReLU:
   def forward(self, inputs):
      self.output = py.maximum(0,inputs)

layer1 = Layer_Dense(2,5) # number of inputs , number of neurons
activation1 = Activation_ReLU()
layer1.forward(X)
print(layer1.output)
activation1.forward(layer1.ouput)
print(activation1.output)
```

```
File "/Users/eungbaekkim9andy/coding/python/NeuralNetwork/NeuralNetwork.py", line 36, in <module>
    layer1.forward(X)
  File "/Users/eungbaekkim9andy/coding/python/NeuralNetwork/NeuralNetwork.py", line 27, in forward
    self.output = py.dot(inputs, self.weights) + self.biases
  File "/Users/eungbaekkim9andy/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nnfs/core.py", line 22, in dot
    return orig_dot(*[a.astype('float64') for a in args], **kwargs).astype('float32')
  File "/Users/eungbaekkim9andy/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nnfs/core.py", line 22, in <listcomp>
    return orig_dot(*[a.astype('float64') for a in args], **kwargs).astype('float32')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

I tried to change n_inputs to np.array(n_inputs ) but I don't think it is working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve the AttributeError:'list' object has no attribute 'astype'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46759801/how-to-solve-the-attributeerrorlist-object-has-no-attribute-astype)

Comment: "I don't think it is working" -- Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in:

```
    activation1.forward(layer1.ouput)
```

Also, not sure if this output is what you're looking for but I changed to a lowercase (x) here:

```
    layer1.forward(x)
    print(layer1.output)
    activation1.forward(layer1.output)
    print(activation1.output)
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cT671.png)

Comment: Just wondering how does changing to a lower case x elimate the attribute error?

Comment: When I change it to lower case x, it gives me this kind of error. 
activation1.forward(layer1.ouput)
AttributeError: 'Layer_Dense' object has no attribute 'ouput'

Comment: @Andykim I see what you mean, I think the issue is with the X variable is what I meant to say

Comment: I see I guess I will change it to a different variable